# Python webscraper using selenium works normally but not when headless

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, docker, headless-browser

I am using python, selenium and the Firefox web-driver to scrape a website over a couple of pages. One of those pages involves executing java-script to simulate clicking a button with an onclick action that changes an HTML table to raw csv.

I am trying to get my web-scraper to run headlessly in a docker container using xvfb and [xvfbwrapper](https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper). I have managed to get selenium to scrape the webpages that don't involve java-script but the ones that do (as described above) fail.

Here is the relevant part of the code from my web-scraping class that fails when running a headless Firefox web-driver in a docker container but works when using a normal Firefox driver outside of the docker container.

```
def getFirefoxBrowser(self):
    firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = firefox_profile, capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    return driver

def getCsv(self,url,browser):
    browser.get(url)

    if waitfor != None:
        element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, waitfor))
        )

    browser.execute_script('vjs_removeChild(arguments[0].concat("_clone")), table2csv(arguments[0]), sr_record_analytics_event("CSV", sr_record_directory(), arguments[0])',javascriptElement)

    rawCsv = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='csv_" + javascriptElement + "']").get_attribute('innerHTML')
    return rawCsv 



from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
vdisplay = Xvfb(width=1280, height=740, colordepth=16)
vdisplay.start()

browser = self.getFirefoxBrowser()
csv = getCsv("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201509100nwe.htm",browser)


vdisplay.stop()
```

The line that fails is in getCsv()

```
browser.execute_script('vjs_removeChild(arguments[0].concat("_clone")), table2csv(arguments[0]), sr_record_analytics_event("CSV", sr_record_directory(), arguments[0])',javascriptElement)
```

And I get this Error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ReferenceError: vjs_removeChild is not defined
```

Let me reiterate: this error only happens when I try run it inside docker where it is headless. When I run this code like "normal" (a full Firefox browser window comes up and I don't use the Xvfb or vdisplay lines of code) I don't get the error message and the web-scraping is successful.

Edit:
I should mention that the javascript code that "is not defnied" in the sourcec of the webpage that im scraping.

Comment: Does this work when you run it headless not inside a Docker container?

Comment: The problem is that since im running off OSX I cant use xvfbwrapper